# How can I define a C++ preprocessor macro through the command line with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I try to set a preprocessor macro in the command line of CMake. I've tried:

```
set generator="Visual Studio 8 2005"
set params=-D MY_MACRO=1
cmake.exe -G %generator% %params% ..\some_project
```

but it's neither defined when I compile nor can I find the name `MY_MACRO` in the files generated by CMake at all, except for `CMakeCache.txt` where it's present in the form:

```
MY_MACRO:UNINITIALIZED=1
```

How can I do it?

Comment: If you solved this by now I would be interested in the solution

Comment: @ybungalobill: 
You can't inject macros from the commandline, you can only modify existing macros that are defined in CMakeLists.txt.
Also, *set params=-D MY_MACRO=1* should be *set params=-DMY_MACRO=1*

Comment: @TimMeyer: yes, see my answer below.

Comment: @ybungalobill I was interested 7 years ago ;) Thanks for providing an answer anyway, I'm sure it will help many others.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The motivation behind the question was to batch build 3rd party libraries, which is why I wanted to avoid modifying CMakeLists. So years later, even though I don't need that anymore, I figured out that it's easily achievable by **means external to CMake**:

- Invoke CMake as usual, no special flags.
- Then:

  - **With MSVC:** The compiler reads the `CL` environment variable to get extra command line arguments. So

    ```
      set CL=/DMY_MACRO=1 %CL%
    ```

    then invoke MSBuild to do its job.
  - **With Makefiles:** The generated makefiles use the `CFLAGS` and `CXX_FLAGS` variables as makefiles are expected to do. So the build can be started by

    ```
      make CXX_FLAGS=-DMY_MACRO=1
    ```

    or by setting the corresponding environment variables.

Comment: This is a good workaround for command line building but I'd also want users to be able to open the generated solution file with the IDE in which case this wouldn't work. It's a pity that even in 2020 there's no way to add to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS rather than specifying (overwriting) them.

Comment: After stumbling on this problem, I found that `cmake -E env CXXFLAGS="-DMY_MACRO" cmake SourcePath` works in my case (src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44357387/1666181). Not sure though if this would override completely too.

Answer (score 42):

A good alternative would be to define a CMake option:

```
OPTION(DEFINE_MACRO "Option description" ON) # Enabled by default
```

Followed by a condition:

```
IF(DEFINE_MACRO)
    ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DMACRO)
ENDIF(DEFINE_MACRO)
```

Then you can turn that option ON/OFF via the command line with CMake using the `-D` flag. Example:

```
cmake -DDEFINE_MACRO=OFF ..
```

To make sure the compiler is receiving the definition right, you can call make in verbose mode and check for the macro being defined or not:

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

This is a good solution also because `make` will recompile your code when any of CMake options changes.

Comment: This requires modifications of the CMakeLists, so it's not a solution (-1).

Comment: @YakovGalka not entierly true, he suggest to change the CmakeLists.txt prior, so the macro can be defined/undefined at subsequent builds.   Agree it doesn't provide mose flexiblity, but for most use-cases it is what people need.

Comment: One can use `add_compile_definitions` instead of `add_definitions`. See [define preprocessor macro through cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017573/define-preprocessor-macro-through-cmake).

Answer (score 24):

Try this: `-D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=/DMY_MACRO=1`

Comment: It half works indeed. It overwrites the value of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. I've tried `-D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="/DMY_MACRO=1 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}"` but `${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}` is not get expanded. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Double-quoted strings on the command line will be expanded by bash. Since you have no environment variable named CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, bash expands it to "", before cmake even sees it. Use single quotes instead.

Comment: @Tolli that doesn't seem to work either. It prevents bash from expanding the variable, but cmake doesn't expand it either. It passes the literal value `/DMY_MACRO=1 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}` directly to the compiler.

Comment: @Tolli: I didn't run it on bash. Not all the world is bash.

Comment: ` -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -DTSI_OPENSSL_ALPN_SUPPORT=0"` seems work for me

Answer (score 1):

One more way is to use the documented [CXXFLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CXXFLAGS.html) environment variable. This environmental variable is used to initialize CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS cache entry, so it needs to be used **when first generating build files**, and if you then need to change the CXXFLAGS value, then you'll need to regenerate the build files again.

E.g.:

```
# CD to the build directory
cd <build_dir>

# Clean the build files including cmake cache
rm -rf *

# Generate build files with the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS containing our MYMACRO define
CXXFLAGS=-DMYMACRO cmake <source_dir>

# Build the project with the MYMACRO being defined 
cmake --build .
```

Answer (score -8):

Unless you have a good reason **not to**, you should use `ADD_DEFINITIONS(<name>=<value>[, ...])`.

Just add the following line to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS("MY_MACRO=1")
```

CMake will take care of the syntax of the switches (be it `-D<name>=<value>`, or `/D<name>=<value>`).

Comment: modifying CMakeLists.txt doesn't count as a command-line solution. And yes, I have a good reason to not do this. I have to automate the build process, and I *should not* change the sources.

Comment: Sorry about the space; I wanted to add a commandline solution, but it wasn't quite what you were looking for. Nonetheless, doing it from the commandline is only going to make your day miserable, trust me.

Comment: Sometimes the commandline is more useful than a gui application and sometimes not. I really don't think that you can say that this will make your day miserable, as it really depends on the situation, skill of the user, and personal preference.