# How to add preprocessor definitions on CMake's command line?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

**Is there a reliable way to add a C++ preprocessor definition on CMake's *command line*?** If there is no cross-platform solution, is there at least a one on Windows?

Specifically, we would like to define the preprocessor symbols `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` and `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` [1] *without* altering `CMakeLists.txt` (because this is part of an automated build for third-party libraries that we don't want to touch).

[1] These preprocessor symbols, together with `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` CMake symbol, allow dynamic linking against Boost libraries on Windows.

Comment: `-DNAME=VAL` is one way.

Comment: @GillBates As far as I know, this defines a CMake symbol, not a C++ preprocessor symbol.

Comment: Not if you add it to the `CXX` flag. `CXX += flags`.

Comment: (From duplicate question, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8564462/3440745) is valid for your case).

Comment: @Tsyvarev But that will overwrite all other CXX flags determined by CMake itself. It does not append those flags (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284275/passing-compiler-options-cmake)).