# cmake compiler boolean switch issue

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm pretty new to cmake. I'm using the following:

```
cmake -DUSE_OLD_CODE:BOOL=FALSE
```

This works fine. But when I change the `FALSE` to `TRUE`, the compiler seems to think that `USE_OLD_CODE` is a file and then complains that it cannot find it.

Below is CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

add_compile_options(-std=c++11 /W4 /wd"4127" /wd"4201" /MP)

IF(USE_OLD_CODE)
    add_compile_options(/D "USE_OLD_CODE")
ENDIF(USE_OLD_CODE)

set( SOURCES
 "main.cpp"
)

set (OLD_CODE_SOURCES
  "OldCode.cpp"
)

set (NEW_CODE_SOURCES
  "NewCode.cpp"
)

IF(USE_OLD_CODE)
  set (SOURCES ${SOURCES} "${OLD_CODE_SOURCES}")
ELSE(USE_OLD_CODE)
  set (SOURCES ${SOURCES} "${NEW_CODE_SOURCES}")
ENDIF(USE_OLD_CODE)

IF(WIN32)
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE} WIN32 ${SOURCES})
ELSEIF(UNIX)
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE} ${SOURCES})
ENDIF(WIN32)

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

thanks

james

Comment: Do you mean you're changing the `FALSE` part to `true` or the `BOOL` part to `true`?

Comment: Could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/10364240/1597714

Comment: I am setting the FALSE part to TRUE. Edited above. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add the `CMakeLists.txt` code also that translates the CMake variable to something your compiler gets.

Comment: Added CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

shouldn't it be `add_compile_options("/DUSE_OLD_CODE")` ?

msvc doesn't expect a space after "/D" IIRC.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235412(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 0):

To enable you can use -DUSE_OLD_CODE:BOOL=ON 
and To disable USE_OLD_CODE use -DUSE_OLD_CODE:BOOL=OFF