# CMakeLists.txt how to include conditional preprocessor

Tags: c, cmake, preprocessor

In cmake how do you do a conditional preprocessor `#ifdef #endif`.

For example there is a `#ifdef #endif` below in a soruce file and I want to include this file during compliation?

How would you do that?

```
#ifdef LWM2M_WITH_LOGS
#include <inttypes.h>
#define LOG(STR) lwm2m_printf("[%s:%d] " STR "\r\n", __func__ , __LINE__)
#endif
```

The full source file is located here: 
[Source file on github](https://github.com/eclipse/wakaama/blob/master/core/internals.h)

And the CMakeLists.txt file is located here:
[CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/eclipse/wakaama/blob/master/examples/client/CMakeLists.txt)

Comment: What do you need? Conditional definition in `CMakeLists.txt` or conditional definition in source file?

Comment: The source file you've linked to is an include file - you include it by having a line like `#include "internals.h"` in your source code.

Comment: @Gluttton thanks, the conditional definition is already in the source file. Sorry if I wasn't clear but I want  this code to be included when I compile so my question is what do I have to put in the CMakeLists file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define preprocessor macro through cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017573/define-preprocessor-macro-through-cmake) or [How to define a C++ preprocessor macro through the command line with CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564337/how-to-define-a-c-preprocessor-macro-through-the-command-line-with-cmake)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add option in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
option (WITH_LOGS "Use reach logging." OFF)
if (WITH_LOGS)
    # Do some related work (if you need),
    # ...
    # and add definition for compiler 
    target_compile_definitions (lwm2mclient PRIVATE -DLWM2M_WITH_LOGS)
endif ()
```

And configure your project:

```
cmake -DWITH_LOGS=ON {path-to-CMakeLists.txt}
```