# Policy-class design: how to add a CMake option selecting the desired class

Tags: c++, cmake, policy-based-design

I wrote the following traits that defines some policy classes:

```
  namespace memory
  {
    struct on_RAM
    {
      template<typename T>
      using pop_sizes_type = PopulationSizeOnRAMImplementation<T>;

      template<typename T>
      using flow_type = FlowOnRAMImplementation<T>;
    };

    struct on_disk
    {
      template<typename T>
      using pop_sizes_type = PopulationSizeOnDiskImplementation<T>;

      template<typename T>
      using flow_type = FlowOnDiskImplementation<T>;
    };
  } // end namespace memory
```

I use these traits to configure the behavior of a simulation class: `MyClass<memory::on_RAM>` or `MyClass<memory::on_disk>`

Eveything works fine, but I would like users of the resulting programs to be able to pick on or the other alternative without having to modify the source code.

I guess I can ask them to overwrite a default implementation by giving an option to CMake, that could give that to the compiler, that could make some compile-time choice. But I have no idea how to technically implement that. Any suggestion?

Comment: `I use these traits to configure the behavior of a simulation class: MyClass<memory::on_RAM> or MyClass<memory::on_disk>` `I would like users of my library/programs to be able to pick on or the other` So users will write `MyClass<memory::on_RAM>` or `MyClass<memory::on_disk>`, they already can do that, there's nothing for you to do.

Comment: @KamilCuk What you propose is what I have been doing for a while for my own use and would work for the template library users, but unfortunately, this is not a solution for non-programmers users that would be interested only in ready-to-use programs. I am looking for a solution that would be external to the C++ code so they don't have to mess with it. I edited the question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Actually, there is a little CMake specific in the problem. E.g. you could use preprocessor conditionals (`#ifdef`) in your code for select the class. [That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564337/how-to-define-a-c-preprocessor-macro-through-the-command-line-with-cmake) tells you how to pass compiler definition in CMake.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Wonderful! This is exactly what I was looking for :) Thank you very much!

Comment: `this is not a solution for non-programmers users that would be interested only in ready-to-use programs` I do believe, that "non-programmer users" will have bigger problems learning two langauges - cmake and c++ - then just C++.  Template specialization (`std::vector<int>`) are really basic C++ concept. `so they don't have to mess with it` they don't have to "mess" with _your_ code, they will write `MyClass<memory::on_RAM>` in _their_ code. `I am looking for a solution that would be external to the C++` You would have to explain more what kind of solution are you searching for.

Comment: @KamilCuk You are right I mis-presented the problem. I work in biological sciences, and some people don't know how to open a terminal: what is fine because the core of their job is something unrelated like wetlab or catching butterflies. So I want to simplify things for them :3 So it's OK if they only have to type `cmake -DCMAKE_ON_RAM`,  but I lose them if they have to modify l.36 of `library/src/core/context.h`. And I don't want to lose potential users lol they is already only a bunch of them on the whole planet ;) Tsyvarev pointed to the solution I was looking for! But thank you :D